# Add bytes during download process. Javascript with blob

Tags: javascript, file, download, blob

I try to download files from Javascript. My code it's only a prototype, but need to validate the concept. My server has 62 files of (512K).

Is it possible to start the download of the file, and append bytes to the current download file process.

So i declare a function "upload" up with a file index (i). This function will deferred with jquery.

```
var up = function (i) {

          //http://localhost/Handler/ReadFileTob64.ashx?index=0
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/Handler/ReadFileTob64.ashx?index=" + i,
            type: "POST"
          }).done(function (data) {

            // var b =  System.Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            blob = b64toBlob(data, "video/mp4", 512, blob);
            if (i < 61) {

              up(i+1);
            } else {
              dfd.resolve();
            }

          }).fail(function (ex) {
            alert(ex);
          });
      }
```

I promise my up function and when it's finish I create a link to download it.

```
dfd.promise(up);
      up(0);

      up.done().then(function () {

            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = "video.mp4";
            a.href = url;
            a.textContent = "video";

            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(a);


      });



    })
```

Actually in this method i load all the bytes (62 files) in the blob, so i presume those bytes will be stored in the memory of the browser.

**Is it possible to start the download of the blog, and append bytes during the download process ?**

There is my complete code .....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {



      var fileType = "video/mp4";
      var blob = new Blob([], { type: fileType });
      var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
      var up = function (i) {

          //http://localhost/Handler/ReadFileTob64.ashx?index=0
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/Handler/ReadFileTob64.ashx?index=" + i,
            type: "POST"
          }).done(function (data) {

            // var b =  System.Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            blob = b64toBlob(data, "video/mp4", 512, blob);
            if (i < 61) {

              up(i+1);
            } else {
              dfd.resolve();
            }

          }).fail(function (ex) {
            alert(ex);
          });
      }


      dfd.promise(up);
      up(0);

      up.done().then(function () {

            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = "video.mp4";
            a.href = url;
            a.textContent = "video";

            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(a);


      });



    })


    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize, blob) {
      contentType = contentType || '';
      sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

      var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
      var byteArrays = [];
      byteArrays.push(blob);
      for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
          byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
      }

      blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
      return blob;
    }
```

Comment: *during the download* like the one from the `<a>` click? Nope not possible. After you downloaded all your chunks from your server, you could do `new Blob(chunks)`, but once you asked the browser to save something with the `<a download>`, you can't modify what will be saved.

Comment: ok. thanks. It's there a maximum of byte that i can save in the blob ?

Comment: Theoretically no. But there is yes, and it will depends for every user.